# Fita target not recognized by vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

i'm having trouble getting a fita target to be recognized by vuforia in unity3d. 
as being a circle it does not have enough features, but is there a way to improve recognizion of a circle pattern image like a Fita in vuforia?

we already tried more constrast or only a section of the fita like the center.

fita image link:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use such a simple image. You need more features. Features are not just contrast between large areas of your image. A feature, put simply, is a sharp change in contrast in some small part of your image. You need many features for stable detection and tracking. A solid circle is simply impossible to track via natural feature tracking.